# Change console out put from PHP

Tags: php, linux

Is there anyway to change console color from an echoed PHP statement in debian? I've got a script that runs from the command line of a debian sever and i'm trying to figure out view all the outputted information in a clearer fashion.

Comment: Specifically the second answer, not the accepted answer

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thank you, I found that one and tried the accepted answer wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can easily change the color of the output. That is, when the terminal supports it.

You can do this manually, as follows:

```
echo "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";
echo "\033[32m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";
```

Or use a more sophisticated way with a library such as 
https://github.com/kevinlebrun/colors.php or https://github.com/abcarroll/simple-ansi-escape where you can have more understandable code, such as

```
echo $c('Hello World!')->white()->bold()->highlight('green') . PHP_EOL;
```

or

```
echo esc::ansiEscape(array('color/blue', 'faint', 'underline')), "I hope you enjoy Simple-Ansi-Escape!");
```

Hope that helps!